# Same Joint Distribution, different conditional and marginal distribution

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution, joint-distribution

I have a group of samples drawn from density function $p(x,y)$, so it has the marginal density $p(x)$ and $p(y)$, and conditional density $p(x|y)$ and $p(y|x)$.

In what way I can construct another group of samples, with the SAME $p(x,y)$ but the $p(x)$, $p(y)$, $p(x|y)$ and $p(y|x)$ are changed?

Comment: Thanks Dilip, my original thought is that $p(x,y) = p(x|y) p(y)$, so if you can "properly arrange" that decomposition, maybe we can get another $p(x,y)$ with different $p(x|y)$ and $p(y)$. Why it is not possible?

Comment: @Lamfeeling It is not possible to "properly arrange" the decomposition since there is no choice in what we can use for $p(y)$: the joint density tells you what $p(y)$ must be, and then $p(x|y)$ is just the ratio $p(x,y)/p(y)$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The joint density uniquely determines the marginal densities:

$$p(x) = \sum_y p(x,y) ~~\text{or}~~ 
p(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x,y)\,\mathrm dy$$ 
(similarly for $p(y)$) and so the conditional densities are also
determined uniquely by the joint density.
So the answer is

> No, you cannot construct another group of samples as you desire.

If the joint density of a population is being *estimated* from the 
samples instead of being known 
*a priori,* then different samples from the population will typically give 
slightly different estimates, and so the estimated $p(x,y)$ will be 
slightly different for the two sets of samples, as will marginals etc. 
Again, your desire to have the *same* joint density and different
marginal densities will not be satisfied.

What you *can* get is the same marginal densities but different
joint densities. A simple example is two Bernoulli random variables
$X$ and $Y$ each with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$.

- If they are independent, $p(0,0)=p(0,1)=p(1,0)=p(1,1) = \frac{1}{4}$.
- But if $X = 1-Y$, $~p(0,0)=p(1,1)= 0, ~p(1,0)=p(0,1) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Consider also two standard normal random variables. If they are *jointly
normal*,  then $p(x,y)$ is the bivariate normal density. As a 
special case, if they are independent, then $p(x,y) = p(x)p(y)$.
But they *could* be marginally normal random variables
that are **not jointly normal** with joint density
$$p(x,y) = \begin{cases}
2p(x)p(y), & \text{if}~ x \geq 0, y \geq 0, \text{or}~ x < 0, y < 0,\\
0,& \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
Note that the random variables are positively correlated in this
case since the probability mass lies entirely in the first and
third quadrants.  This again illustrates that
the same marginal densities can give rise to different joint densities.

What you want, the same joint density but different marginal densities,
is, alas, not possible.

Comment: (+1) Good overview and nice, illustrative counterexample. It is interesting that if we sample from $p(x,y)$ we can recover a pair of iid standard normals $X^\star$ and $Y^\star$ by letting $X^\star = \epsilon_1 X$ and $Y^\star = \epsilon_2 Y$ where $\epsilon_i$ are independent random variables with $\mathbb P(\epsilon_i = \pm 1) = 1/2$.

Comment: @cardinal To recover iid standard normals can we simply use e.g. $(X, Y^*)$ rather than $(X^*, Y^*)$? It seems to me that we don't need both of $\epsilon_1$ *and* $\epsilon_2$ to disentangle $X$ and $Y$.