# Joint probability density function

Tags: normal-distribution

I'm stuck with this question: 
Suppose I have two random variables: A and B such that 
$$A\sim N(\mu_A,\sigma_A)$$
$$B\sim N(\mu_B,\sigma_B)$$

A and B are independent.

I create a new random variable $Y=A+B$
How would the joint pdf of A and Y be? 
i.e. is there an explicit form for $$f_{A,Y}(a,y)$$ where the small letters denote the realised values.

My issue is since Y contains A, I can't just write the pdf as product of two pdf right?

Thanks!

Comment: The dependence, if any, between A and B is crucially important. If you don't understand why, you need to learn the basics of 1st semester undergrad probability theory. Do you even understand what joint distribution and joint pdf are?

Comment: Do you understand what independence of random variables is, and how that relates to their joint distribution and, if it exists, to their joint pdf?

Comment: See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d) for why simply specifying the marginals distributions is not sufficient. There are numerous posts on this topic -- see also [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120861/example-of-two-correlated-normal-variables-whose-sum-is-not-normal) for example, which shows another example indicating why identifying both the marginal distributions and the correlation is still not sufficient.

Comment: Anyone who followed my advice in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33776/real-life-examples-of-common-distributions/156843#156843 , and read at least the beginning of Feller Vol. 2, would of course be familiar with the examples in problems 2 and 3 of III.9 and problems 5 and 7 of V.12, of random variables whose marginal distributions are Normal but which are not jointly normal.

Comment: And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent for an example of uncorrelated normals which are nonlinearly dependent and not jointly normal.  I.e.,, uncorrelated does not mean independent, even for Normals, unless they are jointly Normal.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and advice! Sorry I forgot to say that A and B are independent of each other.

Comment: Hint 1: What is the distribution of Y?   Hint 2: Y and A are not independent, so determine conditional distribution of something given something else, then integrate by using the Law of Total Probability. You need to figure out the details for yourself.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Would you like to post your strategy as an answer? I am sure whoever comes across this question, would benefit from it.

Comment: I provided a hint, not an answer because I don't want to completely do George' s homework for him.  Therefore, in my opinion, it is not worthy of being an answer. I am only telling him what ANYONE ought to know to and be able to do if they've taken an undergrad first semester or quarter introduction to probability course. By the end of such a course, such a person either should not need the hint, or they should be at best a D student in such a class.  That said, there's more than one way to skin a cat, so there are other valid ways of solving the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Hamedani, G. G. (1992). Bivariate and multivariate normal characterizations: a brief survey. Communications in Statistics-Theory and Methods, 21(9), 2665-2688](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610929208830936)), the oldest characterization of the bivariate normal distribution is due to Cramer (1941). It states (using the OP's notation)

> The random vector $[Y,  A]$ has a bivariate normal distribution **if
>   and only if** every linear combination of $Y$ and $A$ has a univariate
>   normal distribution.

Denote

$$\mathbf z = (z_1, z_2)' \in \mathbb R^2$$

and consider

$$W(\mathbf z) = [Y,  A]\cdot  \mathbf z = Yz_1 + Az_2 = (A+B)z_1 + Az_2 = (z_1+z_2)A +z_1B$$

By assumption, $A$ and $B$ are normal random variables. Scaling does not affect normality. Therefore, $(z_1+z_2)A$ is a normal random variable, and so is $z_1B$. Moreover,  $A$ and $B$ are assumed independent, and therefore so are these scaled versions of them. The sum of two independent normal random variables is  a normal random variable. So $W(\mathbf z)$ is a normal random variable, for any $\mathbf z$ (even for $\mathbf z = \mathbf 0$, see comments). But this means that every linear combination of $Y$ and $A$ has a univariate normal distribution, so Cramer's condition is satisfied and $[Y,A]$ has a bivariate normal distribution.

So the joint density will be the bivariate normal density, and the only thing one needs to calculate is the correlation coefficient between $Y$ and $A$, which is trivial.

Comment: The restriction $\mathbf{z \neq 0}$ is not included in Cramer's definition and so should not be included here either. If $\mathbb{z=0}$, $W(\mathbf z) = 0$ _is_ a normal random variable with zero variance. For a vigorous discussion as to whether a constant can be considered to be a normal random variable with zero variance, see the comments following [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30160/6633) to a different question.

Comment: @DilipSarwate You are  right of course, and I adjusted the answer. In my opinion "constants as random variables" is one of those not-so-importnat-things that can (should?) be left out when an important result is to be communicated to a broader, and perhaps not so experienced, audience.