# Gaussian Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, density-function

Assume we have two continuous Normal RV "X" and "Y".
how can I show the conditional PDF f(X|Y) and f(Y|X) is Normal?

Comment: If the claim you refer to in your first sentence is really as you wrote it -- "any linear combination of N Normal RVs is a Normal RV" -- then it's false. Can you also clarify what you mean by "Twins Normal RVs"?

Comment: For example see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189130/is-joint-normality-a-necessary-condition-for-the-sum-of-normal-random-variables and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120861/example-of-two-correlated-normal-variables-whose-sum-is-not-normal

Comment: @Glen_b I edited my Q and make it very simple. Sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: I found an answer to your question in a related thread: see the duplicate.